# Render Menu using embed token

Tags: routes, tokens, nodes

Is it possible to render a menu in a block or a node's body using [embed] or any similar token?

What I want to achieve is to render the main menu in a custom block. I don't want any solution that involves PHP or changes in source code. Token seems like a good option but I'm unable to find a token to render the main menu.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: there is no option to render a menu using token. You can render using php or modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that without coding, you have to create your own module, which will create this token (implementing hook_token_info and hook_tokens) - see example here - http://www.taggartjensen.com/code-snip/drupal-7-create-custom-token-module.

EDIT: I created a simple module out of this - [Token Menu Render](https://drupal.org/project/token_menu_render).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it a lot. Although I have managed my work with mini panels, yet it sounds really helpful and usable. I will look into it. Thanks a lot!